# Enhancing a builder - subclass the builder or create a builder decorator?

Tags: design-patterns

I am designing a new application and thinking of the following problem.

---

**Background information**

I will have a builder class called HouseBuilder to build objects of type House. The builder will provide the following methods:

- buildRoof(),
- buildWindow(),
- buildDoor(),
- etc.,
- getHouse().

In the client code, I will typically use the builder class like this:

```
HouseBuilder builder = new HouseBuilder();
House house = builder.buildRoof().buildWindow().buildWindow().buildDoor().getHouse();
```

This is a classic example of a Builder design pattern in use.

---

**The question**

In the client code, I will need to build a specific type of a house, let's say a cottage. Building cottages from basic building blocks (e.g. as in the above example) everytime I need a new one seems like a lot of unnecessarily duplicated code.

I would therefore create a new builder class, let's say a CottageBuilder, which would allow something like this:

```
HouseBuilder builder = new CottageBuilder();
House house = builder.buildCottage().getHouse();
```

I am unsure what the best approach to design the CottageBuilder is. Two options come to mind:

- have the CottageBuilder be a subclass of the HouseBuilder and use the parent's methods inside the buildCottage method,
- have the CottageBuilder accept a HouseBuilder instance and call it's methods inside the buildCottage method (I would have the CottageBuilder subclass the HouseBuilder anyway, to get polymorphic behaviour - so I would have CottageBuilder become something like a decorator around the HouseBuilder).

Which of the approaches is better?

One drawback of the second approach that I can think of is that the CottageBuilder would need to have a dependency on another HouseBuilder instance and I would make it ask for the dependency in it's constructor. From the perspective of the client code however, it seems weird to be setting a HouseBuilder instance into the CottageBuilder instance.

---

Note that my builders aren't in fact going to build House objects, but rather objects from a different domain. I have decided not to pollute the question with describing the target domain and instead to make up this analogy, which, to my opinion, fits quite well on the original problem.

Comment: Will the `CottageBuilder` always build the same type of house or can it be further customized as with `HouseBuilder`?

Comment: Always the same type. I'm looking for the best way to have a shortcut to create cottages, instead of creating them from basic building blocks everytime I need new ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "builder" generally builds objects in a series of steps, such as the `HouseBuilder` in your example. Your `CottageBuilder` isn't really a builder but a "factory" that returns a specific type of house. So I would have a `HouseFactory` class with static methods for creating different types of houses:

```
public class HouseFactory {
  public static House createCottage() {
    HouseBuilder builder = new HouseBuilder();
    // use builder to build cottage
    return builder.getHouse();
  }

  // more methods for other types of houses
}
```

Comment: Sounds right, thanks! I wouldn't have the createCottage method static though and would have the HouseFactory accept an instance of the HouseBuilder as a constructor argument. It should be easier to test, reuse, etc.

Comment: @DušanRychnovský: I generally avoid static classes, but this is an acceptable use case because `createCottage` is simply a utility method -- as you mentioned earlier, "a shortcut to create cottages" instead of duplicating code. If you really feel the need to test this method, then you should refactor it into smaller testable pieces.